# Mesclar array substituindo resultados iguais

Tags: javascript

Como mesclar um array substituindo os numeros iguais ?

Exemplo:

array1 = `[1, 2, 3];`
array2 = `[2, 4, 5];`

o array3 ficaria `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`
em vez de `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

---

Como mesclar um array substituindo os numeros iguais só nas casas impares dos arrays ? (mesma coisa da pergunta de cima mas só nas casas impares)

Exemplo 1:
array1 = `[1, 1, 2];`
array2 = `[3, 4, 6];`

o array3 ficaria `[1, 2, 3, 6];`

Exemplo 2:
array1 = `[4, 1, 5];`
array2 = `[4, 4, 3];`

o array3 ficaria `[4, 5, 3];`

Comment: Sua segunda pergunta não ficou clara

Comment: A segunda eu não entendi !!!?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com a solução. Separadas as KEYS em impares e pares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Função para reduzir as ocorrencias iguais**

```
var unique = function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```

**Concatenando e substituindo os índices repetidos de um array**

```
// criando arrays e concatenando array1 e array2
var array1      = ["1", "2", "2", "3"];
var array2      = ["2", "3", "3", "4"];
var concatenado = unique( array1.concat( array2 ) );
```

**separando as chaves impares e pares da array com valores únicos**

```
var par   = []; // agrupa chaves pares
var impar = []; // agrupa chaves impares

// separando as chaves impares e pares
for (var i=0;i<concatenado.length;i++){
    if ((i+2)%2==0) {
        impar.push(concatenado[i]);
    } else {
        par.push(concatenado[i]);
    }
}

alert(impar);
alert(concatenado);
```

[jsfiddle online](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzL9gqv/4/)

[Fonte 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903018/1244639) | [Fonte 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8120002/1244639)

Answer (score 1):

*Reposta do:* **Como mesclar um array substituindo os numeros iguais ?**

```
var array1 = [2, 2, 3];
var array2 = [2, 4, 4];
var array3 = [array1[0]];

for(i = 1; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    var tem = false;
    for(j = 0; j < array3.length; j++){

        if (array1[i] === array3[j]){
            tem = true;
        }
    }
    if (!tem){
       array3.push(array1[i]); 
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
{
    var tem = false;
    for(j = 0; j < array3.length; j++){

        if (array2[i] === array3[j]){
            tem = true;
        }
    }
    if (!tem){
       array3.push(array2[i]); 
    }
}

console.log(array3);
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyj97aq3/)

---

*Resposta do:* **Como mesclar um array substituindo os numeros iguais só nas casas impares dos arrays ? (mesma coisa da pergunta de cima mas só nas casas impares)**

```
var arrays1 = [1,1,2];
var arrays2 = [3,4,6];
var arrays3 = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < arrays1.length; i+=2){                                
    arrays3.push(arrays1[i]);
}
i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < arrays2.length; i+=2){                
    var tem = false;
    for(j = 0; j < arrays1.length; j++){
        if (arrays2[i] === arrays1[j]){
            tem = true;                        
        }                    
    }   
    if (tem === false){
        arrays3.push(arrays2[i]);
    }
}
console.log(arrays3);
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftoq0tg4/)

Answer (score 0):

De forma bem simplificada usando a propriedade [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
do Javascript.

```
const concatenarArray = (array1, array2) => {
   return [...new Set([...array1, ...array2])];
 }

 console.log(concatenarArray([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]));
 console.log(concatenarArray([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], [-1, 1, 2, 3]));`
```